# Create New Row in Sheet1 if Value in ((Sheet2, Column A) or (Sheet3, Column A)) Doesn't Exist in (Sheet 1, Column A)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will look in column A on sheet1 and see if it is missing any values from column A on sheet2 or column A on sheet3. If it is missing have the value added to the bottom of the column A on sheet1. The same value may exist on sheet2 and sheet3 but it only needs to be represented once on sheet1.

I'm working with the code below.

```
Sub newRow()

Dim rngSh1 As Range, rngSh2 As Range, rngSh3 As Range, mySelSh2 As Range, mySelSh3 As Range
Dim lastRowSh1 As Long, lastRowSh2 As Long, lastRowSh3 As Long
Dim wb As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb
    lastRowSh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowSh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowSh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngSh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSh1)
    Set rngSh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSh2)
    Set rngSh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSh3)
End With

For Each cell In rngSh2.Cells
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngSh1, 0)) Then
        If mySelSh2 Is Nothing Then
            Set mySelSh2 = cell
        Else
            Set mySelSh2 = Union(mySelSh2, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
If Not mySelSh2 Is Nothing Then mySelSh2.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastRowSh1 + 1)

For Each cell In rngSh3.Cells
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngSh1, 0)) Then
        If mySelSh3 Is Nothing Then
            Set mySelSh3 = cell
        Else
            Set mySelSh3 = Union(mySelSh3, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
If Not mySelSh3 Is Nothing Then mySelSh3.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastRowSh1 + 1)

End Sub
```

I've made every adjustment I can think of but with every change I make I get a different error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why not adding all the missing values in a dictionary, then write all values from that dict at the end of you sheet1.Columns(1) ?

Comment: Which errors and on which lines?

Comment: @GuillaumeBEDOYA i had the similar through on using a dictionary; however, i went the opposite route of adding all known values to the dictionary and appending if the key is not found.  Good ups, dude

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a little bit of time using a `Scripting.Dictionary`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary, sheetNum As Long
    For sheetNum = 2 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(sheetNum)
            Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim rowNum As Long
            For rowNum = 1 To lastRow
                Dim dictVal As Long:  dictVal = .Cells(rowNum, 1).Value
                If Not dict.Exists(dictVal) Then dict.Add dictVal, 0
            Next rowNum
        End With
    Next sheetNum
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim checkableRangeLastRow As Long:  checkableRangeLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim checkableRange As Range:  Set checkableRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(checkableRangeLastRow, 1))
        Dim dictKey As Variant
        For Each dictKey In dict.Keys
            If IsError(Application.Match(dictKey, checkableRange, 0)) = True Then
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = dictKey
            End If
        Next dictKey
    End With
End Sub
```

You add all values in your not-master-sheet into `dict` then loop through that list; if it's not found in your master-sheet, then you add then to the end of the list.

A significant note is that the `Type` of value used as the `dictVal` may cause the `IsError()` statement to always be `True` if it is not the same `Type` as the data being assessed in the `checkableRange`.

Comment: Postscript, do not forget to turn on the reference for `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. The rows that will be evaluated in Sheet2 and/or Sheet3 consist of a string (ColA), an integer (ColB), and an integer (ColC) like: "2020-001A | 1000 | 850". How would I include that "Type"?

Comment: @Noah there are several ways to do that, be it create a single key with all items or assess matching the key in columns(1) and having a subsequent if statement to check columns(2) & columns(3).  If combining, `As String` works just fine; you run into issues when you assess a `Long` or `Integer` against a `String`.  Alternatively, you could define an array to capture the full scope on each sheet, then loop through that array and append un-matched items on sheets(1); the benefit of this allows you to not worry about types and capture all values as is.